# Previous week number and corresponding year in idiomatic Clojure?

Tags: clojure, idioms

I'm learning to be more idiomatic with Clojure. I feel that my following implementation could be more idiomatic and be simpler:

```
  (defn refine-previous-week-and-year [initial-year, initial-week]
  ;; Returns the week number and year of previous week,
  ;; taking consideration if the current week is 1st week of a year,
  ;; then the previous week is the week 52 of the last year.

  ;; If the initial week number is not nil, keep it as the week number.
  ;; If the initial year number is not nil, keep it as the year number.
  ;; If the intial year is nil, return the current year, unless, the initial-week is nil,
  ;; and the previous week is the week 52 of the last year, then return last year. 
  ;; If the inital week number is nil, then the previous week number is current week minus one,
  ;; unless, the current week 1, then the previous week is 52, and the year is last year.

  (cond
    (and initial-week initial-week) [initial-year initial-week]
    (nil? initial-week) (let [previous-week-raw (- (current-week) 1)]
                          (if (= 0 previous-week-raw)
                            [(if initial-year initial-year (- (current-year) 1)) 52]
                            [(if initial-year initial-year (current-year)) previous-week-raw]))
    (nil? initial-year) [(current-year) initial-week]))
```

There are convoluted logic of considering whether the input parameter is nil or not, and the logic of considering the previous week is the last year's.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Yu

**Edit**

Based on comments and suggestions, here is my improved version:

```
  (defn refined-previous-week-and-year
    "
    Returns the week number and year of previous week,
    taking consideration if the previous week is the last week
    (52) of the last year.

    If the raw-week number is not nil, keep it as the week number.
    If the raw-year number is not nil, keep it as the year number.

    If the raw-year is nil, return the current year,
    unless the raw-week is nil, and the previous week is the last week (52)
    of the last year, then return last year.

    If the raw-week number is nil,
    then the previous week number is current week minus one,
    unless the previous week is the last week (52) of the last year,
    and the year should be last year.
    "

    [raw-year, raw-week]

    (let [real-year-and-previous-week (memoize  (fn [] (let [previous-week-computed (dec (current-week))
                                                             year (current-year)]
                                                         (if (= 0 previous-week-computed)
                                                           {:year (dec year) :week 52}
                                                           {:year year :week previous-week-computed}))))
          real-year (fn [] (:year (real-year-and-previous-week)))
          real-previous-week (fn [] (:week (real-year-and-previous-week)))]
      {:year (or raw-year (real-year)) :week (or raw-week (real-previous-week))}))
```

I'm using function and memoize to make the computation of real-year, and real-previous-week lazy. I wonder if it could be achieved by simpler approach?

With (or x y) expression, the logic is simpler, and I have solved the convolution of dealing with raw parameter being nil or not, and the calculation of previous week by using function to capture the calculation.

Really appreciate your help my learning!

Comment: You can use docstring instead of comment. Also, have a look at this: https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few rules you could apply to be more idiomatic:

- Use docstring instead of comments
- Remove comma in function parameter list. Commas are treated as whitespace in Clojure and are generally avoided. Line breaks and alignment are used to provide clarity.
- Replace the pattern (if x x y) with (or x y)
- Replace (- x 1) with (dec x)

---

Your code doesn't seem to work as advertised for all cases and it could be made much simpler, mainly by thinking of the two input values as things that need to be defaulted if they don't exist. After that point the process is always the same

```
(defn refine-previous-week-and-year
  "Returns the week number and year of previous week,
  taking consideration if the current week is 1st week of a year,
  then the previous week is the week 52 of the last year."
  [input-year input-week]
  (let [year (or input-year (current-year))  ; Use current year/week
        week (or input-week (current-week))] ; if none provided
    (if (= 1 week)
      [(dec year) 52]
      [year (dec week)])))
```

---

Edit:

It seems I didn't understand your requirements, but I think your comment is misleading, so I've removed the docstring. To get the behaviour I think you want, I'd split this into two simpler functions:

```
(defn previous-week
  [year week]
    (if (= 1 week)
      [(dec year) 52]
      [year (dec week)]))

(defn previous-week-if-no-week
  [input-year input-week]
  (let [year (or input-year (current-year))]
    (if input-week
      [year input-week]
      (previous-week year (current-week)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution!

Comment: But I realize the difference that I want the non-nil input parameters not to be modified at all.

Comment: Closer to the requirement. It covers the cases with input-week well: when it's set, then no change at all. I need the same logic for input-year, when it's set, no change allowed.